# Best Way C++ Eventing Handling on iPhone and other mobile devices

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

I am writing a C++ library that will need to do some eventing handling.  I intend to call this in and Android environment using JNI, and I also intend to call it from a iPhone application as well. So I want to know the best C++ library or solution for event handling?  I want MIT or BSD type license. Or maybe I could write it in objective C and distribute on both types of devices? I don't have a mac so no XCode right now. I need a simple solution, no threading issues, and no GPL etc licenses.Or is there a way to do this in Native C++ easily without a library.  I am looking for recommendations on this. One thing it will probably also do is connect to SQLite.  Thanks

Comment: Whats the problem with GPL licence?

Comment: It depends what you want, wouldn't a simple observer pattern handle most things?

Comment: Well for one thing is is GPL 1,2,3 etc.  Whats wrong with BSD? or MIT?

Comment: I suppose it would. I mean I kind of like the idea of processing events or commands.  Yes, I think observer would probably work.

Comment: I'm basically trying to reduce the risks of any threading or memory leaks etc. I also don't like thinking about licensing issues.

Comment: I would use a singleton and observer pattern to write your own, just follow the example from Apple's NSNotificationCentre. There will be no licensing issues and it will do exactly what you want. Add in a mutex and it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can cook up something extremely simple using std::tr1::function. An event could just be a function wrapper:

```
#include <tr1/functional>

typedef std::tr1::function<void ()> event;

void my_event_handler()
{
    // handler code here
}

class C {
public:
    void my_method_handler()
    {
        // handler code here
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    event ev;
    ev = &::handler;  // assign an event handler
    ev();             // fire an event

    // same thing, but using a method as a handler
    C c;
    ev = std::tr1::bind(&C::my_method_handler, &c);
    ev();
}
```

The code above is very portable, I run something like this on iOS, Android, OSX, Windows and cygwin.